# How to run a local plugin in grails 1.3.5

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails and I have a local-plugin (that I wrote) that I'm using in conjunction with my project. The local plugin location is configured in BuildConfig.groovy using the *grails.plugin.location* config parameter.

In Grails 1.3.3, the plugin worked fine, however since upgrading to Grails 1.3.5 I get the following error when I attempt to run one of the plugin's scripts:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: web-app\WEB-INF\grails.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
```

I believe that the *grails.xml* file (which it claims is missing) is generated automatically - and the problem may be related to issue [GRAILS-6601](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6601) (however, this was fixed in 1.3.5).

In any case, my problem seems to have occurred due to a change in the _*GrailsBootstrap.groovy* script between Grails 1.3.3 and 1.3.5. Comparing these scripts between 1.3.3 and 1.3.5, I note that a new pluginManager part of the script reads:

```
// There is a pluginManager variable in the binding
            delegate."pluginManager"(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean) {
                application = grailsApplication
                grailsDescriptor = new FileSystemResource("web-app/WEB-INF/grails.xml")
            }
```

This is not present in the equivalent script in Grails 1.3.3 and seems to be causing my problem. I've looked at the release notes and other information, and haven't been able to find if there's something new I need to configure to make local plugins work.

Any ideas how I can avoid this error? Is it a configuration issue, and if so, what am I missing?

Comment: have you tried to re-install the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach used to work for us since 1.1.1 till now, 1.3.6. In `BuildConfig.groovy`, write:

`grails.plugin.location.'my-plugin-name' = "local-plugins/my-plugin-name-0.1"`

Comment: Thanks - but that's what I've been doing - and what I meant by the first line of my query where I said it was "configured in BuildConfig using the grails.plugin.location" parameter. The error I'm getting doesn't seem to be a result of not having this (grails.plugin.location.'my-plugin-name') set, as it was working in 1.3.3 and that value is still (as far as I can tell) set correctly. Moreover, if I grails-upgrade back to 1.3.3 the plugin works, without the error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see. One more dumb comment - did you try `grails clean`?

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone checking this in future, I finally got this working using a combination of "grails clean" and deleting previously generated resources/rebuilding the project etc. I'm not sure exactly what was causing the problem initially - a grails clean alone didn't fix it - however I've accepted @Victor's answer as you do need to have "grails.plugin.location.blah" set and his suggestion to "grails clean" did help me get there in the end!

Comment: Well, sometimes one needs to wipe $HOME/.grails/<version>/plugins or /projects/<project>. Can't tell when exactly.